# functions of deployed contract only return 0

Tags: solidity, geth

[solidity] I deployed a simple smart-contract to a private ethereum network, All the functions return only zero, even one thar explictely "return 170" what may be wrong?
    pragma solidity ^0.5.6;

```
contract Test {
    uint256 myNumber = 70;


    function setMyNumber(uint256 _myNumber)
    external {
        myNumber = _myNumber;
    }

    function getMyNumber ()
    external view returns (uint256) {
        return myNumber;
    }

    function return170 ()
    external pure returns (uint256) {
        return 170;
    }

    function returnNumber (uint256 _number)
    external pure returns (uint256) {
        return _number;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show the contract?

Comment: Update: the geth works fine with solidity 0.4.x, but not with 0.5.x

Answer (score -1):

For anyone with the same problem. The solidity 0.5.X only works after Constantinople, so the private blockchain must be configurated with the " constantinopleBlock: ".